# ORACLE query check record exist or not - hourly

Tags: oracle, date-arithmetic

Example I have table with data below:

```
FORMID | QUANTITY | DATEADDED
1      | 150      | 4/12/2017 2:33:27 PM
2      | 100      | 4/12/2017 3:15:10 PM
```

I want the query to check the data hourly exist or not based on current time.

Example

```
Current time: 18:00
```

So when query check the data, it should no data because We see the last data is at 3:15:10 PM and current time is 18:00(more than 2 hours ago).

I don't have idea how to do it,

```
SELECT * FROM TBQUANTITY WHERE...
```

Comment: So you need data between 18:00:00 and 18:59:59?

Comment: If last date is `4/12/2017 3:15:10 PM` and current time is `4/12/2017 4:15:10 PM`, then should this row  returned ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get all rows where the `DATEADDED` column is between now (using server time) and one hour ago.

```
SELECT *
FROM   TBQUANTITY
WHERE  dateadded BETWEEN SYSDATE - INTERVAL '1' HOUR AND SYSDATE
```

Answer (score 0):

For a simple ad Hoc query to see if there are some records use `SYSDATE` as proposed in the other answer.

If your target is to get all records and process each record only once, more care should be taken.

You can hourly schedule a query selecting the data from tha last hour such as

```
 select * from T where DATEADDED >  trunc(sysdate,'HH') -1/24 
     and DATEADDED <= trunc(sysdate,'HH')
```

Note that this query select the data from the last full hour (*trunc on HH*)
e.g. from 12-04-2017 17:00:00 to 12-04-2017 18:00:00 and you use a half-open interval **not BETWEEN** which would select records with a timestamp of a whole hour twice.